# Hide Opera warning for development purposes

Tags: opera

Is it possible to hide the Opera 12 message:

> Information from this secure page will be submitted to a page that is
>   not secure on ...

I understand the risks, but I don't want to be bothered with this while doing development work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread in myOpera community. It was opened by a user with the same issue.
Unfortunately, it says there's no way to hide these warnings:

> > And how can i disable this behaviour?
>
> You can't, by design. [...]

[link to thread](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1050642)

(It is a pretty old thread, but I think it can fit your question).